# Scala 2.7.x type mismatch error when passing null for a reference type

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

The following Scala code fails to compile in Scala 2.7.7, with a type mismatch error "found: Null(null) required: T" on the last line:

```
/**
 * @param [T] key type
 */
class Key[T] 

class Entry[T](val k: Key[T], val v: T)

def makeEntry[T <: AnyRef] = new Entry[T](new Key[T], null)
```

**I'm fully aware of the evilness of nulls, but suffice it to say that I actually need to do this.** Is this a compiler bug or programmer error?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, T is a type parameter and not a concrete type. I didn't realize this was ambiguous in the original question until I read Carl's response more carefully.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the [correct way](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2794) to do this in 2.7 is:

```
class Key[T]

class Entry[T](val k: Key[T], val v: T)

def makeEntry[T >: Null] = new Entry(new Key[T], null)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the definition that covers `null`:

> Type Null is a subtype of all reference types; its only instance is the null reference. Since Null is not a subtype of value types, null is not a member of any such type. For instance, it is not possible to assign null to a variable of type Int.

In English, this is saying you can't assign `null` to a value type but it's valid to assign to any reference type.

I'm having some trouble figuring out whether `T` is a value or reference type; but that would answer your question.

As you define `T` to be a subtype of `AnyRef`, I guess it's a ref and the "bug" explanation seems the more likely; especially as Mitch Blevins just said the code works under 2.8 .

Comment: It seems to be the consensus that this should work, so I'm going to accept your answer unless contrary evidence comes along.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class Key[T <: AnyRef]

class Entry[T <: AnyRef](val k: Key[T], val v: T)

def makeEntry[T <: AnyRef] = new Entry[T](new Key[T], null.asInstanceOf[T])
```

I'm not sure why the "asInstanceOf[T]" is required, but it seems to be.

Comment: Didn't work in Scala (and I actually can't use that technique anyway because Key and Entry are really Java classes defined in another library)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
def makeEntry[T <: AnyRef] = new Entry[T](new Key[T], null: T)
```

Comment: Same problem using REPL and scala 2.7.5.

Comment: I didn't realize that was valid syntax. :)  Just tried it, and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't have 2.7 handy to test, but I would also try null.asInstanceOf[T]